# Почему выходит FileNotFoundException в jar файле

Tags: java, xml, xmlparser

я хочу создать проект, в котором надо создать jar файл. Проект в IntellijIdea работает, даже когда jar file внутри проекта, а когда перемещаю его в рабочий стол показывает в командном строке -> java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\office_list.xml (Не удается найти указанный файл). Вот так он работает когда запускаю ПРОЕКТ:

```
public Group unmarshall() {
    try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("resources/office_list.xml")) {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Group.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        //write XML to an array of bytes
        //ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //marshaller.marshal(createJavaObjectExample1(), baos);

        //read XML from array of bytes
        //InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
        group = (Group) o;
        //System.out.println(group.getName());

        return group;
    } catch (JAXBException exception) {
        Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, "saveMarshall threw JAXBException", exception);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

расположение 'office_list.xml' файла:

[image: расположение office_list.xml файла]

ну и как же сделать чтобы jar file мог его увидит?

Comment: Эх, мельчает народ - мельчает :(

Comment: Если Ваш файл находится внутри архива Вашей программки, то надо применять функции загрузки ресурсов. `InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/office_list.xml");` Надо только знать как правильно указать путь к ресурсу.

Answer (score 0):

Рядом с исполняемым `jar` файлом должна быть директория `resources`. Т.е:
На рабочем столе должна быть папка `resources` в ней `office_list.xml`.

Comment: так не работает

Comment: @NursultanZhyenbaev Когда вы собираете программу в jar, нужно указать, откуда будет браться `office_list.xml`(внутри jar пакета, или где-то снаружи)

Comment: У вас, похоже, рядом c исполняемым `name.jar`(допустим, файл называется так) должна быть папка: `resources/office_list.xml`. Также, проверьте, что запускаете jar так: `java -jar name.jar`

Comment: как указать что внутри .jar?